# Javascript: indexOf in object literal notation

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I've the following code in my existing project.

```
//selectedColumn is dynamic but will have part of the string
if(selectedColumn.indexOf(const.abc) > -1 || selectedColumn.indexOf(const.abcd) > -1) //selectedColumn can be bc, ab etc
{
    //logic 1
}

if(selectedColumn.indexOf(const.xyz) > -1 || selectedColumn.indexOf(const.wxyz) > -1){ //selectedColumn can be xy, yz etc
    //logic 2
}
//.. so on and so forth
```

I'd like to use the object literal notation instead of this if else ladder.

```
var logicLookup = {
    "???": function(){ //what should be the func name here
        //logic 1
    }
};

logicLookup[selectedColumn]()
```

How would I have the function name inside of the object literal? I believe I cannot do a `indexOf` operation inside of the object literal.

If I give that function a name like 'ab', then I'd still have to do if else again to pull the logic.

```
if(selectedColumn.indexOf(const.abc) > -1 || selectedColumn.indexOf(const.abcd) > -1)
{
    logicLookup["ab"]()
}
```

I want this if to be avoided.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm good if there is any alternative to this if..else code smell statements.

Comment: The pattern you are trying to use is only useful for *exact* matches, not substring matches.

Comment: Yes @Quentin. Is there any alternative or the best way to write so as to eliminate if else statements ?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use that technique for exact-match scenarios. I would do this in two steps:

1- *Normalize* the input, going from a flexible representation to an exact one:

```
function normalize(name) {
  var aliasTable = {
    'ab' : ['ab', 'abcd', 'ad'],
    'xyz': ['xyz', 'wxyz']
  }

  for (var normName in aliasTable) {
    for (var i in aliasTable[normName]) {
      if (name === aliasTable[normName][i]) return normName
    }
  }
}
```

The `normalize` function behaves as follows:

```
normalize('ab')   -> 'ab'
normalize('abcd') -> 'ab'
normalize('xyz')  -> 'xyz'
normalize('wxyz') -> 'xyz'

normalize(anythingElse) -> undefined
```

2- Dispatch the function call:

```
var normName = normalize('abcd')

var handlers = {
  'ab' : function handleAB() { ... },
  'xyz': function handleXYZ() { ... },
}

if (normName in handlers) {
  handlers[normName]()
}
```

Comment: Thanks @slezica. But I'm thinking it'd get complicated if I've to add another condition in the patterns object(like `ad`). I'm not so good at those regular expressions though.

Comment: Ok, let me rewrite it to use arrays

Comment: my common cases involve only the underscore character in the text sometimes and sometimes not. So, the name can be `a_ab`, `b_bc`, `ab` etc

Comment: There! Now with an easy to read conversion table. You can manipulate the name by removing the underscore using logic, but unless there's dozens of cases, this is more explicit and easier to understand

Comment: Looks good @slezica. I'll see if anyone posts any other approaches. If not, I'll mark this as answer. Thank you.